# Spring Cloud Stream: JSON array cannot be cast to POJO list

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

I'm doing some tests of the **content type auto-conversion** of Spring Cloud Stream.

As the [spring-cloud-stream Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#__literal_streamlistener_literal_and_message_conversion) shows. The json format of `GreetingMessage`(`{"greeting":"Hello, world"}`) will be cast to **POJO** `GreetingMessage` object automatically when consumes in the `@StreamListener`. This tests successfully.

**But**, when i change the *output* as `List<GreetingMessage > [{"greeting":"Hello, world"}, {"greeting":"Good morning"}]`, the *input* **WILL NOT** cast it to **POJO** `List<GreetingMessage >` objects, but as **POJO** `List<String>`.

---

So my question is:

- Is this an existing issue or am i doing something wrong?

---

Code:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GreetingMessage {
    private String greeting;
}

@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class GreetingSource {

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<List<GreetingMessage>> greeting() {
        return new MessageSource<List<GreetingMessage>>() {
            public Message<List<GreetingMessage>> receive() {
                return new GenericMessage(Arrays.asList(new GreetingMessage("hello"), new GreetingMessage("hello2")));
            }
        };
    }
}

@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class GreetingSink {
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void receive(Message<List<GreetingMessage>> msg) {
        // handle GreetingMessage
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the message conversion process, where the parameterized type is not considered (just the raw `List` type). Please open an issue GitHub if you think this needs to be supported.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/726) on Github submitted.